# Vue.js @click not execute function when a:href link is exist

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to create notfication, when the notification clicked and linked to his path will decrease the notification length.

```
<li class="header">You have {{ notificationsCount()}}  notif</li> <li>
 <ul class="menu">
    <li v-for="(notification, index) in notif" :notification="notification" :key="notification.id">                  

      <a :href="notification.data.path"              
          @click="markAsRead(notification.id)"
          @mouseup.right="markAsRead(notification.id)"
          class="text-aqua">{{ notification.data.message }}
       </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

```
    methods: {
        notificationsCount() {
            return this.notif.length
        },

        markAsRead(index, id) {
        if (this.notif.length){
                axios.delete(`/notifications/${id}`)
                    .then(() => {
                        this.notif.splice(index, 1);
                        this.notificationsCount();
                    }); 
            }                 
        }
    }
```

The problem is when a :href link is exist, notificationcount not decrease, but when a :href filled with(#) or i used @click.prevent its work to execute the function and notificationcount decreased. how to solve it?

inside  tag i have two trigger @click & @mouseup.right for handle when open new tab. and when i click right its work well and notification decreased because execute through @mouseup.right but when execute through @click its not work. i have to reload once again for decrease notification count

Comment: How do you know notification count is not changed before navigating away from the page? What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected. You can see the counter change before it leaves. When you leave the page, the program is erased. When you come back to the page, it is restarted. If you want data values to persist, you will need to use some kind of persistent storage like [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or a database. You have axios, but I can't use that in my example here.

Following a link to another page is going to unload the current page, so you don't have much chance to see the change happen. Also, you're not correctly finding the item to splice out.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    notif: [{
      id: 1,
      data: {
        path: 'http://www.google.com',
        message: 'Go to google'
      }
    }]
  },
  computed: {
    notificationsCount() {
      return this.notif.length;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    markAsRead(item) {
      const index = this.notif.indexOf(item);
      
      this.notif.splice(index, 1);          
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Count: {{notificationsCount}}
  <ul class="menu">
    <li v-for="(notification, index) in notif" :key="notification.id">

      <a :href="notification.data.path" @click="markAsRead" class="text-aqua">{{ notification.data.message }}
       </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I try this code, ya before leave the page it work, but after page reload notification is back. i don't know where the problem

Comment: When you leave the page, the entire program is erased from memory. If you want the value to persist, you'll need to use `localStorage` or a database. I edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the axios request is not finish yet and page is already redirected to the path. You can refactor the redirect function after axios request is finish.

```
      ...
      <a
        @click="markAsRead(notification)"
        @mouseup.right="markAsRead(notification)"
        class="text-aqua">{{ notification.data.message }}
     </a>
     ...

     markAsRead(index, notification) {
       if (this.notif.length){
            axios.delete(`/notifications/${id}`)
                .then(() => {
                    this.notif.splice(index, 1);
                    this.notificationsCount();
                    window.location = notification.data.path
                }); 
        }                 
     }
```

You don't need bind click and mouseup together, choose either click or mouseup.